# How to open Excel Application from Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to open an Excel file from Python. The code is:

```
import win32com.client
excelApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
book = excelApp.Open(os. getcwd() + '\Output ' + get_date() + '.csv')
```

but I'm getting this error: "AttributeError: Excel.Application.Open". Any idea how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think this attribute should exist?

Comment: why just not use pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html ?

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar I'm not trying to read it into pandas or python. I'm trying to open the Microsoft Excel application itself.

Comment: @ForceBru I don't care about the attribute. All what I want to do is to open Microsoft Excel.

Comment: try this: 
book = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(os. getcwd() + '\Output ' + get_date() + '.csv')

Comment: @RuslanS. Perfect!...that worked but the Excel app was hidden so I had to use excelApp.Visible = True to see it. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code worked as per @RuslnS. 's recommendation:

```
import os
import win32com.client
excelApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excelApp.Workbooks.Open(os.getcwd() + '\Groups.csv')
excelApp.Visible = True
```

This too works as per Jack Taylor's recommendation:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE", "/t", 'D:\\test.xlsx'])
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Microsoft Office docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Microsoft-Office-products-079164CD-4EF5-4178-B235-441737DEB3A6), all Office programs support a `/t` command-line switch to open a specific file. You can use this from Python's [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to open a specific file in Excel.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["excel.exe", "/t", "C:\\Path\\to\\my\\spreadsheet.xlsx"])
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried ```subprocess.Popen(["excel.exe", "/t", 'D:\\test.xlsx'])``` it but I'm getting [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified even though I'm sure hat the file exists. Did you manage to get it working?

Comment: You might need to specify the full path to excel.exe, depending on how your PATH environment variable is set up.

Comment: Yup..that worked, thanks! :-)  ```subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE", "/t", 'D:\\test.xlsx'])```